# Should we prefer to use Bundle.main or UINib when creating custom view from XIB?

Tags: ios, swift

There are 2 different ways, to create custom view from XIB

### Bundle.main

```
extension UIView {
    static func instanceFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: self), owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! T
    }
}
```

### UINib

```
extension UIView {
    static func instanceFromNib<T: UIView>() -> T {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! T
    }
}
```

---

I was wondering, what is the differences among the 2?

Which one is a better way, or it really doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any difference. The former is what I generally use, but just because it's the older version and so what I'm used slightly more used to from before Storyboards. UINib wasn't added until iOS 4. Before that, there wasn't any way to represent the NIB itself, and you couldn't load a NIB from data (NSData/Data). Adding that allows for some tricks when you don't want to cache the NIB, or when you want to load a NIB dynamically (not from the Bundle). But these are really obscure corner cases.

The Bundle version is just a little shorter usually, and what I recommend. But whichever you like. They're equivalent.